# Wordpress: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently installed `ACF Date and Time Picker` plugin, and according to the installation guidelines, I copied the `acf-date_time_picker` folder that comes along with it inside my themes directory, alongside the `functions.php` file. Also, as per the installation guidelines, I copied the following code snippet inside my `functions.php` file:

```
<?php add_action('acf/register_fields', 'my_register_fields');

function my_register_fields()
{
    include_once('acf-date_time_picker/acf-date_time_picker.php');
}  ?>
```

The basic idea behind doing this was to include the `acf-date_time_picker.php` file inside my `functions.php` file. And since that file is included inside the `acf-date_time_picker` folder which is alongside `functions.php` file, I included the path to be included as

`'acf-date_time_picker/acf-date_time_picker.php'`

However, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/functions.php
```

What seems to be the problem here?

EDIT:

Including screenshots for better understanding of my directory paths:

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you trying to edit the file from the admin section?

Comment: @Toretto No I'm not. Modified the file by opening the file on a text editor.

Comment: check for the path you have entered in functions.php for including your plugin "acf-date_time_picker"

Comment: This is the path I've entered in my `functions.php` file: `'acf-date_time_picker/acf-date_time_picker.php'`, as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using underscores `_` instead of dashes `-` in the folder name

```
include_once('acf-date_time_picker/acf-date_time_picker.php');
```

The folder name I'm seeing in the first screenshot is acf-date-time-picker

So try:

```
include_once('acf-date-time-picker/acf-date_time_picker.php');
```

Comment: Yes, I was clearly misspelling my folder's name in the path. Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin->Appearance->Editor** and
 select a different theme from the dropdown on the right. Edit
 its functions.php and see if you find any of the bad code there.